# How can you have two dex files in a androidTest apk when minSdk is < 21?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

why does `assembleAndroidTest` build successfully when over the 64k dex limit in the `androidTest` apk when using AGP 2.3.3? Is this a bug?

Some info:

[Using multidex to create a test APK is not currently supported.](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#testing)

- using android gradle plugin `2.3.3`
- `minSdk` is `16`.
- `multidexEnabled true`
- 72k method references in my `androidTest` apk, split across 2 dex files.
- builds successfully
- runtime crashes on pre-lollipop devices because a dex issue

I noticed this after trying to upgrade to AGP 3.0.

With `AGP 3.0`:

- `minSdk 16`
- `multidexEnabled true`
- `./gradlew assembleAndroidTest` causes `DexIndexOverflowException`, failing the task
- if I set `minSdk 21`, then `:assembleAndroidTest` succeeds. There are then `70k` method references across `3` `classes.dex` files.

Answer (score 0):

Multidexing the test apk is actually supported (multidex 1.0.2 feature), but broken by a [bug in 3.0 AGP](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37324038).

[Google's documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#testing) is incorrect.